How to satisfy hidden Python dependency conflict between "apache-beam" and "google-cloud-bigquery"?
I am unable to use both "apache-beam" and "google-cloud-bigquery" packages in the same Python project, but there are no warnings about dependency conflicts, either. It's unclear to me how to go about debugging this so that both packages can co-exist in my project.
I suspect the culprit is whatever C dependencies pyarrow has, but it's not clear to me how to fix this other than either (a) keeping my pipeline code in a separate repository to my jobs code or (b) playing whack-a-mole with package and Python versions until they sync.
Reproduction steps:

In a fresh environment, run: pip install google-cloud-bigquery
Run python -X faulthandler -c "import google.cloud.bigquery", it should print nothing.
Then install apache-beam: pip install apache-beam
Run python -X faulthandler -c "import google.cloud.bigquery" a second time.

You should see the something similar to the following SegmentationFault error:
Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

Current thread 0x0000000102466e00 (most recent call first):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1233 in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 573 in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 676 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178 in _find_and_load
  File "/Users/jamesroseman/workspace/new-project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyarrow/__init__.py", line 65 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178 in _find_and_load
  File "/Users/jamesroseman/workspace/new-project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery_storage_v1/reader.py", line 34 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178 in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1234 in _handle_fromlist
  File "/Users/jamesroseman/workspace/new-project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery_storage_v1/client.py", line 26 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178 in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1234 in _handle_fromlist
  File "/Users/jamesroseman/workspace/new-project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery_storage_v1/__init__.py", line 23 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178 in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1128 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178 in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1128 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178 in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1128 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178 in _find_and_load
  File "/Users/jamesroseman/workspace/new-project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 61 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178 in _find_and_load
  File "/Users/jamesroseman/workspace/new-project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/__init__.py", line 36 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178 in _find_and_load
  File "<string>", line 1 in <module>

Extension modules: zstandard.backend_c, charset_normalizer.md, requests.packages.charset_normalizer.md, requests.packages.chardet.md, google._upb._message, grpc._cython.cygrpc, fastavro._logical_readers, fastavro._schema, fastavro._read, fastavro._logical_writers, fastavro._validation, fastavro._write (total: 12)
Segmentation fault: 11


Did you install apache-beam or apache-beam[gcp]? The latter contains already the most common gcp modules (see documentation)
